# Unable to send desired data in session's user object in Next-Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to send the set of custom session object to client side in Next-Auth's callbacks function. The code in `app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js` looks like

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
          });
          const db = client.db("test");
          const user = await db
            .collection("users")
            .findOne({ email: credentials.email });

          if (!user) throw new Error("User is not found!");

          if (user) {
            const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password
            );
            if (!checkPassword) throw new Error("Password is incorrect!");
          }

          return {
            id: 1,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
          };
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, user }) => {
      session.user.id = user._id;
      session.user.name = user.name;
      session.user.username = user.username;
      session.user.email = user.email;
      return session
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as POST, handler as GET };
```

In my client side, it returns only email and name in the session's user object.
How to include the other fields in the session ?
Any help on this would be appreciated.